# Integrate a plug-in to Eclipse IDE

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a plug-in source code, when i export it to jar , i copy it into Eclipse/plug-in/ and restarted Eclipse.

But i can not find it in in the menu Window --> Preferences.

I tried this method also :

1) Open the export wizard, either Open the plugin export wizard File > Export... > Plug-in Development > Deployable plug-ins and fragments

2) Select your plug-ins or features to export and install

But still can't find the plug-in in preferences Menu.
I'm using Eclipse Juno

Comment: Did you acually install it?

Answer (score 0):

The `plugins` folder is for plugins downloaded via the plugins manager. To use locally developed plugins easily, copy the jar into the `dropins` folder. You may have to create that folder if it doesn’t exist yet (and restart eclipse, of course).